# I have t9 flourescent bulbs, what ballasts can I use?

Tags: lighting

I have a bank of 12 t9 bulbs. I would like to purchase some ballasts, however, t9 ballasts are no where to be found except for circline bulbs. I have straight tubes. I would like to know if I can use instant start t8 or instant start t10 ballasts. Or if anyone knows where to find instant start T9 ballasts that would be helpful as well

Thanks
-J

Comment: What the rest of the number on the bulb F??T9?????

Comment: F20T9/BL 20W Fluorescent Blacklight Bi-Pin Base

Comment: I just googled F20T9 ballast and found quite a few choices.

Comment: Everything I'm seeing is a circline ballast with connector. That is for circular flourescents, I need ballast for tubes, which I still havent found.

Comment: Did you type F20T9 ballast or just t9 ballast?  http://www.buylightfixtures.com/f20t9-magnetic-fluorescent-ballast.aspx is one choice.

Comment: I have googled the full F20T9. That is one option, however I specifically need an instant start ballast, and preferably one that isnt 28 dollars when I have 12 to wire. Thinking maybe I sell the T9 and buy t8's at this point. Thanks for the lead though.

Comment: Do the fixtures have an instant start ballast now? I doubt it but if they do then get the exact part number of the ballast and google that.  T9 is kind of an oddity, but I've seen that black light bulb before.  Does the fixture have starters?

Comment: I am working on building a printing unit for alternative photographic processes, and was looking for my last part needed, the instant start ballasts. The T9's are too obscure for me to keep up this search, I appreciate all the help you have given me everyone, I have decided to trade in for the T8 version of the lights instead. Ballasts are much easier and cheaper to come by.

Comment: Yea for instant start you'll have to move to T8 it appears T9 only has magnetic ballasts available.

Comment: Good money after bad.  Sell the bulbs you have on eBay and put your money into that which is common and cheap, ie. T8.   Oh, you did that lol.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [18-20W black light balast](https://www.interlight.biz/light-bulb/HITACHI-F20T9/BL) there are others. make sure to google the entire number F20T9/BL and look for the bi pin models. (You will get less hits on circle lamps with the BL as that is a standard bi pin).

Answer (score 0):

T9 is a very odd size. Switch to T8 -- it's very common. If you could find T9 ballasts, they would probably cost more than a T8 ballast plus T8 tubes. The sockets are probably identical.

Better yet, look into replacing them with LED lighting. You can get retrofit LED tubes that fit fluorescent fixtures, and the cost probably isn't much different than new ballasts and tubes.